# How to use whereBetween clause with a function?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a table which contains a `created_at` column, and based on the `created_at`, I get another date called: `expired_at`. However, the `expired_at` date is not recorded in the database.

How can I filter my data in Laravel to show records between `fromDate` to `toDate` based on `expired_at`.

I only can see that the only option I got is to make a record called `expired_at` in the database and then run something like the following

`$data=Table::whereBetween('expired_at', [$fromDate, $toDate])->get();`

So What's the best solution? How to use `whereBetween` with a function that calculates the `expired_at`?

Comment: First you'll need to actually save something in expired_at, before you can use it. If you're using Eloquent, you can add an [event](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#events) to set the expired_at when the record is created.

Comment: depend on "what is the relation between `created_at` and `expired_at`" mostly

Comment: You probably can't use Eloquent `whereBetween()` for this, as to determine `expired_at` you'd need to get the record, modify it's `created_at` variable, then query again for `created_at`; doing this for every record is redundant and performant heavy. Use some DB data logic to query all records for `created_at {date_modified} BETWEEN etc etc` (not sure which DB you're using). Honestly, just save `expired_at` to the database; will make your life much easier.

Comment: @aynber Actually I can't add the expired_at record to database due to of DB design options.

Comment: @N69S I have a function that calculates the expireDate, it depends on created_at and some other fields, fields in another tables actually.

Comment: @TimLewis I don't have the option to save it. I'm using mysql.
One suggestion just told to me is to create a db view

Comment: If you can't save `expired_at` to the database, you have to do some MySQL date modification when querying. If `expired_at` is `created_at + 30 days`, then you'd do something like `WHERE(DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 30 DAY)) BETWEEN ... AND ...`. That would simply be done via eloquent like `->whereRaw("DATE_ADD(...)");`

Comment: @TimLewis instead of DATE_ADD() I already have a function that calculates the `expired_at` date, but it takes one instance of the model Table as its parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately the calculation of expiry date is not simply add to `created_at` some days.

Comment: Simply adding 30 days was just an example. If you already know how you're calculating `expired_at`, use that in a `->whereRaw("{logic to calculate} BETWEEN ... AND ...");`. Or better yet, get whoever is in charge of your database to add an `expired_at` column. *"I don't have the option to save it"* - You haven't given a reason *why* that is, so I can only speculate.

Answer (score 0):

with my experience, it's better to put calculate process on your application instead of using your database engine in order to calculate your date!

for this case, you can use `Laravel's Eloquent` in order to achieve your goal.

here some example of code you can use inside your application:

```php
class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected $table="your table name in databse";


    public function scopeExpireDateBetween($query, $fromDate, $endDate)
    {
        //i assumed you're using Carbon library
        $created_at_begin_date = $fromDate->minusDate(5);
        $created_at_end_date = $endDate->minusDate(5);
        return $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$created_at_begin_date,$created_at_end_date]);
    }
}
```

as you can see, I added a scope inside your model and you can call your model from controller like below.

```php
public function index()
{
   $results= YourModel::expireDateBetween("your expriration begin date", "your expiration end date")->get();
}
```

you can check laravel's documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs) for more information